# How to query on all Expando entities that have a certain dynamic property?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I want to query the datastore for Expando entities that have a certain dynamic property filled out. That property, however, is not a boolean. I want to get all the entities that have a certain dynamic property filled out.

```
class Entity(db.Expando):
    name = db.StringProperty()

#I want to query something like this
entities = Entity.all().filter('address') #note below
```

Note: I just want to query all entities that have the dynamic property address filled out. I'm not querying if their address matches so and so.

Is that possible? How?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no direct way to do this, but you can kludge around it a bit:

```
entities = Entity.all().filter('address >=', None)
```